# Stored Procedures for inserting,Deleting and Updating evey single table of Information_Schema

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, information-schema

I want to write a script to make stored procedures for insert , delete and update every single table of Information _ Schema , I came up with this code but I have problems in procedures input parameters and the way to insert , delete and update them, can anyone help me please?

```
DECLARE AutoProc CURSOR GLOBAL
FOR
    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
OPEN AutoProc

DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TotalField NVARCHAR(600)=''
DECLARE @Parameters NVARCHAR(600)

FETCH NEXT
FROM AutoProc
INTO @Schema,@Table

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

DECLARE AutoFields CURSOR GLOBAL
FOR
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=@Schema AND
    TABLE_NAME=@Table AND
    TABLE_NAME
    IN
    (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE= 'BASE TABLE'
    )
OPEN AutoFields

DECLARE @FieldName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @DataType NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Size NVARCHAR(10)

FETCH NEXT
FROM AutoFields
INTO @FieldName,@DataType,@Size

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

IF  @DataType='NVARCHAR' OR @DataType='nvarchar'
BEGIN
SET @TotalField=@TotalField+'@'+@FieldName+' '+@DataType+'('+@Size+'),'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @TotalField=@TotalField+'@'+@FieldName+' '+@DataType+','
END

FETCH NEXT
FROM AutoFields
INTO @FieldName,@DataType,@Size
END

CLOSE AutoFields
DEALLOCATE AutoFields

SET @Parameters =SUBSTRING(@TotalField,1,LEN(@TotalField)-1)

EXECUTE('
CREATE PROC USP_INS_'+@Schema+'_'+@Table+'
@parameters NVARCHAR(600)='+@Parameters+'
AS
BEGIN 

INSERT '+@Schema+'.'+@Table+'
VALUES(@parameters)

END')

EXECUTE('
CREATE PROC USP_UPD_'+@Schema+'_'+@Table+'
@parameters NVARCHAR(600)='+@Parameters+'
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE '+@Schema+'.'+@Table+'
SET 

END')

EXECUTE('
CREATE PROC USP_DEL_'+@Schema+'_'+@Table+'
parameters NVARCHAR(600)='+@Parameters+'
AS
BEGIN

DELETE '+@Schema+'.'+@Table+'
WHERE 

END')

SET @TotalField=''

FETCH NEXT
FROM AutoProc
INTO @Schema,@Table
END

CLOSE AutoProc
DEALLOCATE AutoProc
```

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393917/free-sql-server-stored-procedure-generator

Comment: In the time you spend ironing out all the quirks of trying to automatically generate your procedures you could probably just write them out anyway. Using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` gives you no way of identifying computed columns, which you cannot insert to, or update, and the same applies for identity columns. You have not considered anything for the where clause in the delete or update statements, should this be by primary key? There may also be fields you don't want updated, such as `CreatedDate`, so this would need to be excluded from update statements.

Comment: As a final thought, consider using an ORM, then you don't need to worry so much about creating a procedure to insert, delete and update every table.